# OR in real life vs OR in Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I stumbled upon this issue.
Imagine sentence:

> David take cake OR gift

In my understanding of English language David can now take either cake or gift **but not both**.

Am I right?

If I am right does this mean that OR as used in English language is different from OR in mathematical logic? Because in mathematical logic David could take both cake and gift.

But I came to another situation also.

Imagine:

> Either David or Nick will be at home.

In this case, I think if **both** of them will be at home, above sentence is still true.

So why is in this case OR similar to OR from mathematical logic?

Did I use different ORs in above two sentences? What am I missing?

Do operations like OR, AND in mathematical logic need to resemble OR and AND from English language? and what are consequences if they don't?

Comment: What if some one asked you "Did David take the gift or the cake?"  And the answer was he took both.  Or neither.  Was the question wrong in real life?  Does OR change meaning when it is a sentence vs. when it is a question.

Comment: @fleablood: I think that "Did David take the gift or the cake?" will typically be interpreted not as a yes-or-no question, but rather as a forced-choice question with the possible answers { "the gift", "the cake" }.

Comment: Possibly.  Which would make it like the logical rather than "real world", right?  But with the proper inflection it could be "Well, did he take the gift ... or the cake?"  Point is, in real world there are usually contextual assumptions.  "He took one.  Which?" or "I don't know what happened;  Did he take any?"  Its not that "real world" is one interpretation and logic is another.  It's that logic and real world mutually reflect each other but logic is clear and precise while real world can be ambiguous.

Comment: English was not designed to be a precise formal language.

Comment: As noted, "or" in most natural languages is ambiguous; the "primacy" of the *inclusive* meaning in math log, from [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) to R&W's [Principia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) is due mainly to the possibility of a simple definition of $\to$ [ $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$ ].

Comment: How about *normal* in mathematics vs. *normal* in real life? or *regular* or *perfect* or *function* or *derivative* or *line* or *circle* or . . .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both of the English sentences you've written are correct - the word *"or"* in English is **ambiguous**, it can mean both the logical operation `OR` and the logical operation `XOR` depending on the context.

In mathematics, we have decided that *"or"* will **only** mean the logical operation `OR`.

It is usually the case that in mathematics, it is ideal for things to  resemble our everyday experience as much as possible (e.g., `3+2=5` resembles our experience with three apples and two apples together making five apples). However, in mathematics we also usually want more precision than everyday experience, at least for something as basic as what the word *"or"* means. There is no **requirement** that any mathematical term resemble the corresponding thing in English, or anything else from the real world, but we do generally strive for the mathematical terms we create to be somewhat evocative of the appropriate ideas.

Comment: I think this is the culprit: "depending on the context."

Comment: What consequence does the fact that OR in mathematics doesn't necessarily resemble OR from English can have?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: There isn't really any consequence; we just need to be careful not to mistake natural-language contexts for mathematical contexts.

Comment: I asked this because IMO math needs to resemble real world in some sense if we want to apply results from mathematics to real world - isn't that the case? If the models are different how can we use math for benefit in real world?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: That's true, but what the word *"or"* means is only a superficial difference. What is important is being able to encode the aspects we care about from a real world situation as mathematical statements, and if the encoding uses words in a different way, that's fine.

Comment: So as far as I can understand say Math logic isn't concerned with real world that much, only it cares to build a framework for logical deductions - and if real world happens to reflect same rules as math logic, then you can apply results from math logic to real world. Would you agree?

Comment: I would agree with that statement. The point I'd like to make is that if mathematical logic uses a particular string `or` to express the idea of inclusive or, or uses some totally different string like `foobar`, doesn't matter at all to what is being expressed (the same can be said for natural language).

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: For example, in any programming language I'm aware of, the word `or` means the same as mathematics, i.e., it means inclusive or. That has not impeded the ability of programs to represent real world situations at all, it merely means that if we want to program our computer to represent a situation where in English we would use *"or"* to mean exclusive or, we have to use a different piece of the programming language for that.

Comment: Yeah that also sounds true; I was more concerned with things like I mentioned in my previous comment (e.g. how much math must be related to reality - I think this is related with platonism in math) - but you said also you agree with that. So I think I am fine with it so far.

Comment: It's not a problem with math, it's a problem with English language. In other languages there is no ambiguity. In Latin there is `aut` that means exclusive or and `vel` that means inclusive or (`vel` is sometimes used in math too)

Comment: These are called "inclusive disjunction" and "exclusive disjunction" to signify that the former can have both disjuncts as true, while the latter does not allow that.  This is not restricted to mathematics either, but also logic and English.  If I say "I might head to the store, or stop by a friends' place" it's implicit that I could hypothetically do both.  As Giorgi said, it depends on context.

Comment: @edc, and "*vel*" is where we actually get the symbol $\vee$ from.

Answer (score 5):

The English word "or" has lots of different meanings, and the logical OR operation is only one of those meanings.

Here are some sentences that seem to use the word "or" to indicate the logical OR operation:

> Either David **or** Nick will be at home.
>
> I hear a hissing noise. Either the air is leaking out, **or** there are snakes in here.

Sometimes the word "or" indicates the logical XOR operation:

> I see that each person is only taking a slice of cake ***or*** a slice of pie. Why not both?

The word "or" can be used to indicate a list of options, in which case the meaning is neither the logical OR nor the logical XOR. In fact, the meaning is more similar to a logical AND.

> You can have the soup **or** a salad. (You are allowed to choose the soup, *and* you are allowed to choose the salad, but you are not allowed to choose both.)
>
> This car has two color options: blue, **or** red. (Blue is one of the color options, *and* red is one of the color options.)
>
> The blue car costs \$20,000 and the red car costs \$30,000. I have \$40,000 to spend, so I can afford either the blue car **or** the red car. (I can afford the blue car, *and* I can afford the red car, but I can't afford both.)

The word "or" is used to ask "which one?" In this usage, the word "or" definitely doesn't indicate any logical operator, because it doesn't form a yes-or-no question:

> Would you like cream **or** lemon, Mr. Feynman?

The word "or" can be used to make a threat:

> Give me some ice cream, **or** I'll scream!

All of these are different meanings of the word "or", and only the first meaning corresponds to the mathematical "or".

---

> Do operations like OR, AND in mathematical logic need to resemble OR and AND from English language? and what are consequences if they don't?

Well, the logical OR and AND operators are named after the corresponding English words, because the meanings of the logical OR and AND operators resembles the meanings of "or" and "and" in English.

There doesn't *have* to be a correspondence. For example, the logical IF-THEN (material implication) operator doesn't correspond to any common meaning of the word "if" in English. The consequence of this is that millions of students are confused by this operator.

Here's an example of a confusing IF-THEN sentence. Using the logical IF-THEN operator, the sentence "IF there are people on Mars, THEN there are no people on Mars" is true. But using the ordinary English meaning of the word "if", the sentence "if there are people on Mars, then there are no people on Mars" is false, or at least disagreeable.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the third example works. "You can have the soup `XOR` you can have the salad" is the case, not "You can have the soup `AND` you can have the salad" (which means "you must have both").

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Well, my point is that the phrase "You can have the soup or a salad" (as said by a server on a restaurant) is not equivalent to a logical sentence of the form "p OR q" or "p XOR q". Neither the OR operator nor the XOR operator means "p and q are both available options, but mutually exclusive".

Comment: I would have said that the third examples are all `XOR`: Having the soup excludes you from having the salad; Likewise; having the blue car excludes you from having a red one, etc.. Why doesn't `XOR` mean _p and q are both available options, but mutually exclusive_? Isn't that actually what it _does_ mean? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Also, the first example with the hissing - That sounds like an `XOR` situation, it is probably one or the other, and very unlikely to be both - I think that the speaker of that phrase would not intend to convey the possibility of both snakes and a leak, either one or t'other, but not both. :-)

Comment: @Greenonline Well, suppose that the soup is available but you're not allowed to have salad. Then it's still true that "(you can have soup) XOR (you can have salad)", but it's no longer the case that "you can have the soup or a salad"

Comment: @TannerSwett This is a good example, but I wonder what in fact the soup or salad example logically expresses. It seems to be more like "You can have (soup XOR salad)", since it is making a statement about all the possible choice sets $\{\mbox{soup}\}$ (allowed), $\{\mbox{salad}\}$ (allowed), $\{\mbox{soup},\mbox{salad}\}$ (not allowed), $\emptyset$ (not allowed?). In this case it would look like "you can have any choice set $A$ satisfying $\mbox{soup}\in A$ XOR  $\mbox{salad}\in A$" (and it's not clear if the non-allowed choices are also asserted by the sentence).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Take a look at linear logic. It has a "multiplicative conjunction" operator, which is interpreted as "both of these together"; an "additive conjunction" operator, interpreted as "your choice of either of these two"; and "multiplicative disjunction", interpreted as "one of these two, and you don't get to choose". The [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/) article about it is really good.

Comment: @TannerSwett In your first two example blocks, you've mixed up `OR` and `XOR`. In the first one, it's *either* this or that (i.e. this `XOR` that); in the second it's "this or that or both", i.e. this `OR` that.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I have them the way I intended, but the OR examples might not be very clear.

Comment: @TannerSwett Re-reading the second `<blockquote>`, I now understand what you mean by it, and agree that it is right. However I also agree that the `OR` examples aren't clear at the moment ("either" strongly suggests `XOR` to me).

Answer (score 2):

**You should sparingly use the word "either" (with "or") in mathematical writing.** Logically it is equivalent to plain "or" but in English use it tends to emphasize "not both." So this is just confusing for the reader who has to wonder: "we have agreed it does not change the meaning, but are you using it because you think it does?" You will also notice in plain English sometimes "or" is underlined, capitalized or written in boldface to mean "exclusive." This is another thing you shouldn't do in math writing.

In mathematics you have to resort to "exactly one of A or B" or "A or B but not both." **And you should need extra verbiage:** exclusive-or is a strictly stronger claim with more information. So it should take more time to express this since your proof requires more involved information.

Answer (score 1):

The logical `OR` and `AND` do not need to, as you have observed, have the same value as in the English language.

$A \lor B$ is true if at least one of  $A,B $ is true, else false. $A\land B $ is however true if both  $A$ and $B $ are true.

In the English language, OR is most used as the logical exclusive OR (`XOR`), I guess. "Either...or" however means exactly that.