# Simple probability question involving "either...or..." statement

Tags: probability

Here is the  question :
A card is drawn from a standard deck of 52 cards.
Find the probability that the card is either a five
or a black card.  $[A] \frac4{
13}[B] \frac{15}{26}
[C] \frac{17}{52}
[D] \frac{7}{13} $

I thought you have 2 cards that are both five and black, they should not be included in  "either five  or black " case, the probability is $\frac{4+26-2-2}{52}=\frac{1}{2}$. However,  this is not one of the 4 choices. The only one that seems to be right is [D] $\frac{7}{13}$, in which case the two cards that are both 5 and black are included in the calculation. Should or shouldn't we include these two cards?

Comment: In mathematical use, "or" almost always includes "both".  Thus "$A$ or $B$" is true if *at least one* of $A,B$ is true.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072162/or-in-real-life-vs-or-in-mathematical-logic)

Comment: The wording is admittedly a little ambiguous, but I think by default you should assume that any "or"s are inclusive unless specified otherwise. So I would include the two cards.